# Time elapsed between dates

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to know the percentage remaining between two dates.

I've used this code:

```
$(function () {
    var end = $('#data').text();
    var formattedDate = new Date();
    var day = formattedDate.getDate();
    var month = formattedDate.getMonth();
    month += 1;
    var year = formattedDate.getFullYear();
    if (day < 10) {
        day = "0" + day;
    }
    if (month < 10) {
        month = "0" + month;
    }
    var today = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
    remaining = Math.round(((end - today) * 100) / today));
    alert(remaining);
});
```

But it does'nt work.
Any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: How do you define a percentage between two dates?

Comment: use the milliseconds of date. With these you can do percent calculations as you like. Math.round is not able to parse your date strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're subtracting two strings, which is why it won't work.

Subtract two Date objects instead, and you'll get the milliseconds between them (ignoring the maths as to what you define as a % of 2 dates).

```
var now = new Date();
var then = new Date($('#data').text());

var remaining = Math.round(((then - now) * 100) / now);
```

You can still, of course, get your formatted string of DD/MM/YY via;

```
var formattedDays = (now.getDay() < 10 ? "0" : "") + now.getDay();
var formattedMonth = (now.getMonth() < 9 ? "0" : "") + (now.getMonth() + 1);
var formattedDate = formattedDays + "/" + formattedMonth + "/" + now.getFullYear();
```

Note that you have an extra closing parenthesis at the end of your `Math.round()` line as well.

Comment: You can't subtract date objects either.

Comment: Another issue with OP's code is that OP has an extra parens at the end of the round statement `..today));` vs. your correct `..now);` So you should add that to your answer. Also I do not understand why this is getting downvoted.

Comment: @Juhana: Works for me. `>>(new Date()) - (new Date()) // 0`

Comment: @Juhana:-1 to you. date object can be subtracted.

Comment: @chiliNUT: Thanks... didn't notice the `)`; I've added it to my answer accordingly.

Comment: Ah, you're right. (The `remaining` calculation returns 0 unless the other date is relatively far away.)

Comment: @Juhana: Even that shouldn't be the case. They should get converted to milliseconds before the subtraction, which means even `>>x = new Date(); y = new Date(x - 1); x-y; //` works for me...

Comment: @Matt Right, but when you do `Math.round((x-y) * 100 / y)` the difference must be large enough for the calculation inside `Math.round()` to be larger than 0.5.